# Rails 4: Use carrierwave as download-only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, carrierwave

I have a `User` model like this:

```
# profile_pic is of type TEXT in Database
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :profile_pic, ProfilePicUploader
end
```

I'd like Carrierwave to work as download only. In other words, I'd like to do `user.profile_pic.url` and receive the url where the pic is kept, along with a signature, expiration, etc.

What I don't want is for Carrierwave to interfere when I try to save a user's profile pic. For example

```
user = User.first
user.update(profile_pic: 'random_string')
```

I want Carrierwave to stay out of it, and let me save whatever string I want in `profile_pic`.

However, I can't get to update `profile_pic`, because Carrierwave is expecting an instance of a `ProfilePicUploader` instead of a string.

What can I do to just use Carrierwave to download files, but never to upload files?

Comment: not sure i understand the question but maybe `remote_url_profile_pic` could help

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss I've edited my question so my intent becomes clearer